# Finding all the clients of a group

Tags: c#, signalr, jabbr

I am using SignalR in my application.

In order to add or remove clients to a Group we use this API

```
Clients.Group.Add(clientID, groupname)
```

This is working fine.

My goal is to get the reverse of it i.e

I need to get all the clients of that group. I need to apply foreach on it and perform some operation in database.

Is there any API for finding all the clients of a group?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible. You'll have to manage groups manually if you want this functionality.

> There is no API for getting a group membership list or a list of groups. SignalR sends messages to clients and groups based on a pub/sub model, and the server does not maintain lists of groups or group memberships.

Taken from [here](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/working-with-groups). There are also examples on the same page on how to implement groups using a database server or Azure table storage.

Answer (score 0):

This link shows how to add groups members to a database. You must override the Task OnConnected event handler.
Once you do that, you should be able to do whatever else you need in the database.
http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/working-with-groups